# Does one ‘have’ an academic degree, or is one ‘in’ an academic degree?

Tags: grammaticality, historical-change

I have always referred to an academic degree as something I possess—e.g. ‘I have a degree in `$subject`’.

However, I recently had to get my degree certificate out for a job interview and noticed that it says the following: ‘It is hereby certified that `$name` has been duly admitted to the degree of Master of Science in `$subject`’. Same for my Bachelor's.

So what *is* an academic degree, and how should it be referred to? **Is it something one *has*, or something one is *in*?** Do I *have* a Master's degree in `$subject` or am I *in* the Master's degree for `$subject`?

Comment: During your studies, _you_ are _in_ a program _in_ a subject. Afterwards you _have_ a degree. The degree is _in_ a subject. It depends on the ... um... subject. Of the sentence.

Comment: I suppose maybe when you talk about *having* a degree, you really mean the certificate?

Comment: The sentence you quote doesn't say that you are *in a degree.* It says that you have been *admitted to the degree of X in [subject]*. The *in* comes before the subject of the degree, not before the word *degree.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One meaning of **degree** in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/degree) is:

> **degree**
>   NOUN
>
> **4** An academic rank conferred by a college or university after examination or after completion of a course, or conferred as an honour on a distinguished person.

Note that **rank** is mentioned, which explains why the certificate is phrased

> It is hereby certified that Rumps has been duly admitted to the **degree** of Master of Science in XXX

The ranks, as you know, progress from Bachelor, through Master, to Doctor. The Masons and other societies rate progress by numerical degree, for example "reached the 3rd degree".

Informally one refers to a university qualification as **a degree**. So Rumps has/holds a Master's degree in XXX.

---

The prepositions "in" or "on" could be used while you are studying:

> Rumps is in a degree program.
>   Rumps is on a university course.